# How to get html code parsed as copyable text with jquery

Tags: jquery

I've gotten this thing to put the strings together. I found the easiest way to store the parts of the URL was in divs, somehow. Anyway, what I want is for all of this to come together and output as code that the user can then copy and use. The HTML keeps rendering, though, even when put inside a `<code>` or `<pre>` element. IDK what I'm doing wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#generate").click(function() {
    $("#output_code").show;
    var stuff0 = '<code>';
    var stuff1 = $('#stuff1').text();
    var stuff2 = $('#username').val();
    var stuff3 = $('#stuff3').text();
    var stuff4 = $('#invite_text').val();
    var stuff5 = $('#stuff5').text();
    var stuff6 = '</code>';

    $('#output_code').append(stuff0 + stuff1 + stuff2 + stuff3 + stuff4 + stuff5 + stuff6);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Username: <input type="text" id="username"><br/>
Invitation text: <input type="text" id="invite_text" value="Follow me on the site!">
<a id="generate">generate link</a>
<div id="stuff1" style="display: none;">
  SOME HTML
</div>
<div id="stuff3" style="display: none;">
  SOME HTML
</div>
<div id="stuff5" style="display: none;">
  SOME HTML
</div>
```

Comment: You can use the jQuery html function, check it https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp

Answer (score 0):

1) You're asking the id `output_code` to show in your JQuery but it is never defined in your HTML code !

2) Replace all HTML tags (`<` and `>`) by it's HTML code `&#60;` and `&#62;` with regex

3) For the copy in clipboard, I created a temporary input with the code, then I selected it and copied the content. In the end, I remove the temporary input as you can see

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#generate").click(function() {
    $("#output_code").show;
    var stuff1 = $('#stuff1').html();
    var stuff2 = $('#username').val();
    var stuff3 = $('#stuff3').html();
    var stuff4 = $('#invite_text').val();
    var stuff5 = $('#stuff5').html();
    
    var all_code = stuff1 + stuff2 + stuff3 + stuff4 + stuff5;
    
    var all_code_formatted = all_code
    .split('<')
    .join('&#60;')
    .split('>')
    .join('&#62;'); // replace HTML tags, I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it with regex but I don't know how to do it
    
    $('#output_code').html('<pre>' + all_code_formatted + '</pre>'); // Render the formatted code
    
    $('#output').html(all_code); // Render the result
    
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val(all_code).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove(); // Create temporary <input> with your code non formatted, select and copy it and then remove the <input>
    
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Username: <input type="text" id="username"><br/>
Invitation text: <input type="text" id="invite_text" value="Follow me on the site!">
<a id="generate">generate link</a>
<div id="stuff1" style="display: none;">
  <a href="https://www.example.com">SOME HTML</a>
</div>
<div id="stuff3" style="display: none;">
  <div>SOME HTML</div>
</div>
<div id="stuff5" style="display: none;">
  <p>SOME HTML</p>
</div>

<h2>The code</h2>
<div id="output_code"></div>

<h2>What it renders</h2>
<div id="output"></div>

<textarea placeholder="Press ctrl+v to Paste the copied text" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Did this answer to your question ? Please feel free to ask any question about my code :)